# Is it possible using Valence to upload files to the "Manage Files" area?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I see a number of routes to upload various files into D2L, including News, Content modules and the like - http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/fileupload.html however, is there a route to update a file into the "Manage Files" area of an org?  For example to programmatically create a CSV for the CCB tool and upload it to the proper location?

The org that I have is one for "Course Branding" and the content path is something like
go to the course->edit course-Manage files and the Url /content/enforced/7974-ACB/ and there are 4 subdirectories there.  I'd like to create a file in one of the subdirectories but not sure what the route should be.  Any ideas?

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can only add files to an org unit's `Manage Files` area if that org unit has course content, because you must use the course content APIs to add the file data. You must also [create a course content topic of type file](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-content-modules-%28moduleId%29-structure-) in order to upload file data to the course's `Manage Files` area.

The `Url` property for the [ContentObjectData](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#Content.ContentObjectData) JSON you send up indicates where in the course's `Manage Files` area the uploaded file will get stored: it must therefore be a legal path within your course's existing content space, and a file name that's not yet been used. Note that you can't update the underlying file you've already uploaded, or delete it, through the API. However, you *can* delete the content topic used to insert the file in the first place: the content topic will go away, but the underlying file will remain behind in the `Manage Files` area.

This is not a pleasant workaround, but it does seem to be a workaround.